# ElasticSearch Docker Swarm Cluster Issue: "master_not_discovered_exception"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to configure a 3-node docker swarm with Elasticsearch cluster on it. Here is the docker compose file used:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  elastic01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elastic01
    volumes:
       - kesdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch
    ports:
       - 9200:9200
       - 9300:9300
    environment:
       - node.name=192.168.1.249
       - cluster.name=sfty-elk
       - http.port=9200
       - transport.tcp.port=9300
       - transport.host=localhost
       - node.master=true
       - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
       - network.host=0.0.0.0
       - discovery.seed_hosts=192.168.1.250,192.168.1.251
       - cluster_initial_master_nodes=192.168.1.249,192.168.1.250,192.168.1.251
       - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
       - bootstrap.memory_lock=false

  elastic02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elastic02
    volumes:
       - kesdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch
    environment:
       - node.name=192.168.1.250
       - cluster.name=sfty-elk
       - transport.host=localhost
       - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
       - network.host=0.0.0.0
       - discovery.seed_hosts=192.168.1.249,192.168.1.251
       - cluster_initial_master_nodes=192.168.1.249,192.168.1.250,192.168.1.251
       - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
       - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
    depends_on:
      - elastic01



------ etc.
```

## Here is the error in the log files

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-13T17:53:15,428Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "sfty-elk", "node.name": "192.168.1.251", "message": "publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}"}
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-13T17:53:25,892Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "sfty-elk", "node.name": "192.168.1.251", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{192.168.1.251}{1yM9Z0JxQFK1HT7kc5RauQ}{NW1nXax2Tiu1zwTKEbxErQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=33561579520, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; discovery will continue using [192.168.1.249:9300, 192.168.1.250:9300] from hosts providers and [{192.168.1.251}
```

=======================

I have being trying multiple options by mentioning attributes in the docker compose file, but still the  same issue.
Like:
1. Using transport.host=localhost or transport.host=192.168.1.249
2. network.bind_host=0.0.0.0

Here is the IP address of my first host:

```
ifconfig
br-bcfdef6bce3b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:27:89:77:98  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:78:86:1e:97  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker_gwbridge: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:42ff:febd:2468  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:42:bd:24:68  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.249  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::f89e:1dff:feb6:ad67  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:9e:1d:b6:ad:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58365982  bytes 23016720461 (21.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1902  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13045633  bytes 1414222643 (1.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 141  bytes 13772 (13.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 141  bytes 13772 (13.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethbce5267: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5066:22ff:fef7:b87c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:66:22:f7:b8:7c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 23201  bytes 3663983 (3.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32794  bytes 3479431 (3.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:05:08:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Can you please help out in resolving this. Am I missing any attributes in the compose file?

Thanks in advance